# delay function not working right

Tags: jquery, append, delay

I have a tricky problem. When pushing on a button, the content of a div should fadeout, delay, change it to another content, fadein.

```
$('.content-area').fadeOut(500);
$('.content-area').delay(500).empty().append(creation).fadeIn(500);
```

But when it runs this code the content switch while its fading out then it delays, then its shown. Any solution?

Comment: Try it all in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll want to use the callback function.

```
$('.content-area').fadeOut(500, function(){
  $(this).empty().append(creation).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Just to be clear... a callback is called after the function completes. So in this case, after the `fadeOut` completes, then the other things happen.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Callback to the FadeOut function:

```
$('.content-area').fadeOut(500, function(){
    $('.content-area').empty().append(creation).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Works great, thank you, but the other post contains $(this) and that's better for me:)